# Load Model From More Than One URL

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

How can I load different attributes for a model using different URLs?

E.g. I have 3 different and independent URLs that will return some attributes and I want to add all of those to a single model, suppose that I have the promise returned by all of them like this:

```
var model = //...    

$.when(nameAttributes, addressAttributes, metaAttributes).then(
function(nameData, addressData, metaData) {
    return _.extend({}, nameData, addressData, metaData);
})
.done(function(allData) {
    model.set(allData);
    doStuffWith(model);
});
```

Is there a way to turn that into this:

```
model.fetch().done(function(){ doStuffWith(model); });
```

Comment: To avoid complexity, i would have different renders in the view attached to each of the models youre fetching. for example: `View.render()` will handle the main view with maybe gif loaders on the data that is being fetched. then `View.renderAddress()` will handle the address model .. so on. In the `View.intitialize()` i would do `this.addressModel.on('change', renderAddress)` and so on

Comment: If you want me to help you further, please make a working jsfiddle of your code and i will show you what i mean WITH your use case.

Comment: sorry. Its `this.listenTo(addressModel, ..` not `this.addressModel.on` <- this is the old way, its been a while :/

Comment: PLEASE! Do NOT use that what i wrote in the answer. Do what i said ^ there. With each of the calls being a model and then listing to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.. Ok, this should do what you want. I STRONGLY suggest you do NOT take this route. Keep the data separately in individual `Model()`s that way you can update it and pull it when ever you need to. If you take this approach saving data will be a disaster.

http://jsfiddle.net/kjhvwxg4/

PS. I tried to not add any more code then i had to, keep in mind this will probably not handle error handling very well since `xhr` will never throw an error, you need to catch it yourself -- i didnt want to spend the time coding that since this is just a proof of concept.

```
var Model1 = Backbone.Model.extend({
    fetch: function(options) {
        options = _.extend({
            parse: true
        }, options);
        var model = this;
        var success = options.success;
        var error = options.error;
        options.success = function(resp) {
            var serverAttrs = options.parse ? model.parse(resp, options) : resp;
            if (!model.set(serverAttrs, options)) return false;
            if (success) success.call(options.context, model, resp, options);
            model.trigger('sync', model, resp, options);
        };
        options.error = function(resp) {
            if (error) error.call(options.context, model, resp, options);
            model.trigger('error', model, resp, options);
        };

        // custom code starts here

        var call1 = $.getJSON('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
        var call2 = $.getJSON('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/2');
        var call3 = $.getJSON('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/3');
        var xhr = $.when(call1, call2, call3);

        // mimics the same triggers the normal backbone does
        model.trigger('request', model, xhr, options);

        xhr.done(function(one, two, three){
            var resp = _.extend(one[0], _.extend(two[0], _.extend(three[0], {})));
            options.success(resp);              
        });

        // we still need to send back an event handler
        return xhr;
    }
});

var model = new Model1();
model.fetch();

model.on('sync', function(model) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(model.toJSON()));
});
```

Comment: Works great, I just really need to think about saving data this way ):

Comment: Right. Thats why this is a very BAD idea. Please dont do it. Think of your kids!!!